# For Loop for Regression in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, regression

I'm trying to run regression for the CAPM model.
This is the formula *Ri= a+b(rmrf)+e*
my Ri is XS1
I have XS1-XS10 and want to run the regression and store them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit a model with multiple dependent variables simultaneously.

```
reg <- lm(paste0("cbind(", paste0("XS", 1:10, collapse = ","), ") ~ rmrf"), 
          data = df)
summary(reg)
```

Comment: Oh thank you Roland! and what if I need to access the beta in the regression of XS1? 
I try reg$XS1, reg[1] but neither work.

Comment: `coef(reg)` extracts the coefficients as a matrix where each column corresponds to a response variable. If you need statistics you can do `summary(reg)` or even stuff like `lapply(summary(reg), "[", "coefficients")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in (1:10)){
  assign(paste0("reg_", i), lm(paste0("XS", i, "~rmrf", sep= ""),data=df))
 }
```

This is how you do it. `paste0` helps you to add the `i` into your formula. And you will have reg_1 through reg_10 .
`assign` helps you to assign to the first part the input of the formula from the second part. To reg_i the formula of lm(..).

Comment: No, this is not how you do it. Use a list to store the models instead of misusing `assign`.